# load html files by its names in alphabetical order with include php

Tags: php, include, alphabetical

I got this code on my site

```
<div id="tips-wrap">
    <?php
    include('news/games/02GA.html');
    ?>
</div>
<div id="tips-wrap">
    <?php
    include('news/games/03GA.html');
    ?>
</div>
```

it works pretty well, but I want to chage it, so it can load the files by its names in alphabetical order with the last first, but I need it to cycle with the new news

something like this:

```
<div id="tips-wrap">
    <?php
    include('news/003.html');
    ?>
</div>
<div id="tips-wrap">
    <?php
    include('news/002.html');
    ?>
</div>
```

so when we update the site with 050.html the code loads it in the first slot of the page.
I dont know if this is possible, I´m new with php

Comment: Put the names of the files in an array, sort that array and cycle over it to include the files.

Comment: Also you want to use classes instead of IDs, as the latter must be unique!

Answer (score 1):

Put them in an array, sort and include:

```
$includes = array("news/003.html", "news/002.html");
rsort($includes);

foreach ($include in $includes) {
    echo '<div class="tips-wrap">';
    include $include;
    echo '</div>';
}
```

I also took the liberty to use classes instead of IDs, as @Marcel mentioned.

Comment: Use classes, not IDs :)

Comment: This solution still needs an array to be filled. Since the filenames can be sorted, why not read an entire folder with `opendir` and `readdir`, put the filenames in an array and sort. That way an added file is immediately included

Comment: @BasWildeboer agreed, but that's outside the scope of my answer. And it still needs an array, which was my point. Feel free to provide the `readdir` solution.

Comment: ok I´ll try that, but with the array I need to specify the name of the file? because right now we only upload the new html file with the same name and it overwrite the old one and take its place, we are trying to avoid to modify the page that its loading it beacause the same file its loaded by diferent pages across the site... I dont know if I can use some varible to specify the name of the files in the array?

Comment: @BasWildeboer thats what we are lookin for, beacuse this files are the thumbnails of the news so they gon on the main page, their section page and in each news so it need to be updated all over the site only uploading the file, thats what we have now but I need to improve the process even more

Answer (score 0):

This solution reads the directory in which the files are stored and uses an array+sort to generate your html.

```
$dh = opendir([pathtonewsfolder]);

$includes = array();

while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
    if($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
        $includes[] = $file;
    }
}
closedir($dh);

rsort($includes);

foreach ($includes as $include) {
    echo '<div class="tips-wrap">';
    include [pathtonewsfolder].'/'.$include;
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: your code do open the folder and read it but say this: Warning: include() [function.include]: Unable to access newsfolderfilename.html in home/user/public_html/prueba.php on line 145... but it do read the folder because it got the file names right..   thanks for the help

Comment: maybe if we focus on the name of the files, not in the array because all the markup is done, something like: include('news/(a variable here).html'); ?

Comment: Hmm, i see. A slash between the path and the filename should do the trick. Edited my code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one and I think it will resolve your problem

```
<?php
   $dir = '/news/games/';
   $d = dir($dir);
   $arr = array();
   while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
       if ( ($entry != '.') && ($entry != '..') && (strstr($entry,'.html') !== FALSE) ) { 
              $arr[] = $entry;
       }
  }
  $d->close();

  arsort($arr);

  foreach($arr as $nam => $val) { ?>
   <div id="tips-wrap">
     <?php include('news/games/'. $val); ?>
   </div>   
 <?php
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: this code give me this

Warning: dir() [function.dir]: SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. The script whose uid is 835 is not allowed to access /       thanks anyway